# Having trouble Referencing Attributes of an Initialized Array Object

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to write a class named Matrix that's comprised of a two dimensional array. However, I'm having trouble reference other initialized Matrix objects in the main class. Specifically in my add method.

```
public class Matrix {

private int rows;
private int cols;
private double [][] m;

public Matrix (int r, int c){
    rows = r;
    cols = c;
    m = new double [r][c];

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++){
            m [i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}
public Matrix add (Matrix m1) {

    Matrix m2 = new Matrix(rows, cols); 

        for (int i = 0; i < this.rows; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < this.cols; j++){
                m[i][j] + m1[i][j] = m2[i][j];
            }
        }


    return m2;
}
```

The IDE says on line
 m[i][j] + m1[i][j] = m2[i][j];
that "Array required, but Matrix found"

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the problem? You just said you are having issues, please add more details :)

Comment: You are using your matrix object as if it were a 2D array. The compiler has no idea what object[r][c] means. You would have to implement getter and setter methods.